# iPhone SDK: UIVideoEditorController hides trim control behind navigation bar

Tags: iphone, video, sdk, editor, controller

This was reported for SDK 4.3 beta on an Apple developper forum.

This controller was working fine until I upgraded to Xcode4 release.

The trimming control is hidden behind the navigation bar.

It displays properly only when the status bar is visible. which I disable in the entire app.

Looks like a bug was introduced in 4.3

has anyone seen this

Cheers

JP Semery

Comment: I get this problem even in SDK 4.2. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong comment. I get it after SDK 4.3. Did you get any solution?

Comment: No. I posted the same issue on the Apple developers forum without answer. For now I just enable the status bar for this controller only which is the only workaround I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround that you can use. (it wasn't clear from the comments what to do).

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```